# $("...").click(function () { }) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a dialog to open upon click of a  tag. Below are my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ConfirmDeletePage").click(function() {
            if (confirm("Confirm delete page?") == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My html:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 10px;">
    <a href="#" id="ConfirmDeletePage">as</a>
</div>
```

Any idea why the dialog is not opened?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded on page?>

Comment: @Tushar:  I believe so, yes.  The div is in a partial view.

Comment: Use `$(document).on('click', '#ConfirmDeletePage', function() {`. Let me know if this works

Comment: This works, however, if I use a HTML.ActionLink with same id it does not work.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

There might be many reasons for it why it is not working.

Like:

> 1. You may have used same id twice or more in that page.
> 2. Jquery Conflict.
> 3. Jquery Library not loaded properly.

To solve these types of problem always try to look once in firebug console. It helps to solve problem very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have jQuery loaded or the path to it is wrong. Your code works just fine.
You should verify how your `script` is loaded.

Made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/prmrf8qs/) with your code and is working.

First, try to see if the jquery library is loaded, then if is loaded verify if you have a correct path to that library.

Another way is to include an online version of the jquery to see if works:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script‌​>
```

There can be other problems. Use inspect element to see if you have any errors in your console.

Comment: How can I load jQuery?

Comment: just add jquery in your code like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Note that your Pc is connected to internet if u add the above ,else download it and refer it locally